# I am using ionic-angular, I am trying to connect ngx-mqtt client. it is working fine in some devices and not woking in some devices

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework

this is my ionic info:

```
  Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 5.4.16 (C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.7.0
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 12.1.4
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 12.2.5
   @angular/cli                  : 12.1.4
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 4.0.0

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 10.0.0
   Cordova Platforms : android 9.1.0
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.2.1, (and 8 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res : 0.15.3
   native-run  : 1.3.0
```

I am adding mqtt connection details like host, port, client dynamically. could you please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Is there more detail aside from "not working"? Could you provide the stack trace from the logcat if possible?

Comment: I am facing a similar issue,
I have a simple web app (Angular using NGX-MQTT) that subscribes to an MQTT Topic and prints the received messages. This works perfectly on my Laptop/browser. but when I use Cordova to create the app and install it on my mobile, I do not see any message.

Comment: Allow access to websockets. It worked for me.